# Device Channel Rules for All mobile phones and Tablets?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, device-channel

I am developing master pages for different devices, my target is to develop different master page for Desktop, Mobile phones and Tablet.

Default device channel works for desktops, “$FallbackMobileUserAgent" works for both mobile phones and tablets but I want to design different master page for all tablets.

Is there any fall back rule that targets all tablets? and any rule that targets mobile phones only?

Update: I found "ipad" and "iphone" inclusion rule works across all apple devices. What about other devices?

Answer (score 2):

Device Channel rules are pretty simple because they support substrings of the user agent. The big challenge is to find the correct substring.

**For phone rules:**

If you include the word "phone" instead of iPhone then you can cover "Windows **Phone**" and "i**phone**". In addition you need to add **mobile** for the android devices. The word mobile is on android tables

**For tablet rule:**

You need to add **Pad** for i**Pad**. **Android** for android tablets and so on.

What most people don't understand on device channels is that you cover basically group of devices not single devices alone. I think this is the most common misunderstanding.
You can also use the same master page by using device panels in case you just want to hide some parts of the web site.

You will find a nearly complete list of devices and user agent string on the this Website:

[User Agent Strings](http://www.webapps-online.com/online-tools/user-agent-strings)

I also covered some things in this nearly 2 year old [slide share presentation.](http://www.slideshare.net/Birk0ff/responsive-web-design-vs-device-channels-what-about-device-channels)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Agents strings on this site:

```
http://www.webapps-online.com/online-tools/user-agent-strings
```

This result is final:

Channel 1: Tablets
**Tablet

iPad**

Channel 2: Mobile
**Mobile

Phone**

Channel 3: Tablets 2
**Android**

All other devices is Desktop which is the Default and Last Channel.